# What is the easiest way to make StyledTextCtrl look like a TextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, textctrl, wxstyledtextctrl

The only additional features I need from [StyledTextCtrl](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/stc.StyledTextCtrl.html#phoenix-title-styledtextctrl) are the following:

1. Change caret width using `SetCaretWidth(pixels)`
2. Change caret colour using `self.SetCaretForeground(colour)`
3. Change entire background colour to transparent (or alpha). I don't know how to do this.
4. Change Font (face and size). I don't know this either.

Other than that I want it to behave exactly like a normal [TextCtrl](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextCtrl.html#phoenix-title-textctrl). ie. No scrollbars, no multilines etc. A lot of info [here](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/index.html), but it is overwhelmingly big! So how much code will I have to write before I shoot myself in the foot?

---

<sup>There's a sample model [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/StyledTextCtrl%20Log%20Window%20Demo?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=colourlog.py), for quick testing.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (4) with a plain `wxTextCtrl` without any problems, so if you can live with just this, I'd strongly suggest just using the standard control instead. You can [make the window transparent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#af14f8fd2ed2d30a9bbb5d4f9fd6594ec) but this is not implemented in all ports (notably not in wxMSW) currently. The other two points are extremely unlikely to be ever possible with the standard control as it's really supposed to use the standard caret.

If you really need (1) and (2) you will have to use the non-native `wxStyledTextCtrl` but then you really should abandon any idea to make it behave exactly like the native control, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you. I am using a `TextCtrl` at the moment. This is more of an upgrade that I would like to try if possible. So far, I haven't been able to make any progress.